# Estimating two normal random numbers with one equation

Tags: futures, factor-models, brownian-motion, pca, multivariate

*Subtitle: Estimating the correlation of the shocks driving two commodities in
two multi-factor models*

I am fitting two 2-factor models to electricity and gas futures, respectively.

In order to extend this framework to a multi-commodity model I have to
integrate correlation.

The models are ([HJM-type model from forward interest rate models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heath%E2%80%93Jarrow%E2%80%93Morton_framework)):

$\frac{dF_{E} (t,T)}{F_{E} (t,T)} =σ_{1,E} (t,T) dW_{1,E} (t)+σ_{2,E} (t,T) dW_{2,E} (t) $

$ \frac{dF_{G} (t,T)}{F_{G} (t,T)}=σ_{1,G} (t,T) dW_{1,G} (t)+σ_{2,G} (t,T)dW_{2,G} (t) $

where $dW$ are Brownian Motion increments and $F(t,T)$ are the futures prices at $t$ with maturity $T$ for electricity (E) and gas (G). That is, the logarithmic return on
the futures is modeled (fraction on the left side of equation).

I estimate the volatility functions σ via Principal Component
Analysis, so $dW_{1,E} (t)$ and $dW_{2,E} (t)$ are independent by
definition. 
The same applies for the two Brownian Motions driving the
futures price changes for gas futures.

But since electricity and gas futures prices are correlated, I would
like to model this correlation by correlating the Brownian Motions.

I am looking for 4 correlation coefficients:

$dW_{1,E} (t) $ to $ dW_{1,G} (t) $

$dW_{1,E} (t) $ to $ dW_{2,G} (t) $

$dW_{2,E} (t) $ to $ dW_{2,G} (t) $

$dW_{2,E} (t) $ to $ dW_{1,G} (t) $

Now I wanted to estimate which shocks $dW$ led to a specific original
(observed) return series $\frac{dF(t,T)}{F(t,T)}$ and then calculate how these
shocks are correlated. Then I would just use BMs with that
correlations in my model. The problem I have is that I have two shocks
to estimate, for electricity $dW_{1,E} (t)$ to $dW_{2,E} (t)$, but
only one return data point and thus only one equation. Nevertheless, I
know $dW_{1,E} (t)$ to $dW_{2,E} (t)$ are independent standard
normally distributed. Does that help?

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve that equation for the shocks?

Or any ideas how else the correlation could be integrated into this model?

Comment: Maybe this will help. If we have that $\langle W_1,W_2\rangle = \rho t$ then we can write that $dW_2(t) = \rho dW_1(t) + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}dW_1^\perp (t)$, where $dW_1^\perp(t)$ is a perpendicular brownian motion.